# US Presidential Election by County

Tags: data-request, usa, elections

I'm trying to find election data from 1789 to last general election, down to county level. I was lucky to get for only 2002 on this page [Center for Congressional and Presidential Studies](http://www.american.edu/spa/ccps/Data-Sets.cfm). I was wondering if anyone has a credible web link to resources that can provide me with these sets of data.

Comment: Previous answer with some leads: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6583/where-can-i-find-data-on-the-winner-of-the-presidential-popular-vote-by-u-s-cou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find data on the winner of the presidential popular vote by U.S. county, for as many elections as possible?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6583/where-can-i-find-data-on-the-winner-of-the-presidential-popular-vote-by-u-s-cou)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the senate or house has an archive of pdfs going all the way back...but again, its pdfs.
[Open Elections](http://openelections.net/) is going to be your best bet, although you aren't going to find all of the data you seek, you'll find a lot down to county/precinct level.
[Here's one from Virginia with both](http://openelections.net/results/#va).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022-04-20, I was able to access and download presidential election results by county for the years 2000 through 2020 at the Harvard Dataverse, using this url:
https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/VOQCHQ