# High-quality voter (partisan) data for the United States

Tags: data-request, usa, elections

What is the best publicly-available data source for the geographic distribution of Republican and Democratic voters in the (individual) United States? I'm happy with either a presidential or congressional election focus, but I suppose the latter would be preferable as I'm looking into gerrymandering.

I understand that collecting, modelling, and generating such data is presumably a major statistical effort that many private organizations undertake, but perhaps there is some decent publicly-available dataset?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here already about [voting](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+voting), many US. Maybe your answer is already there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find data on the winner of the presidential popular vote by U.S. county, for as many elections as possible?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6583/where-can-i-find-data-on-the-winner-of-the-presidential-popular-vote-by-u-s-cou)

Comment: To be clear, are you looking the number of registered Democrats/Republicans/etc, or the number of people who voted for a specific Democratic or Republican candidate? Keep in mind, people may vote for one party for President, but another party at the state level.